# How to fix margin between posts?

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot of issue]

As in the image, there are 3 posts in a row. I don't know how to make the gap be, for example, 20% between each item. With reference to the image, I want the distance to be as marked with the red dashes, instead of the current distance (as shown by the blue arrows).
It's either in `.container` or `.post`, and I couldn't figure it out.

This is the code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.post {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 20px); /* 3 posts per row */
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.3s ease;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
}

.post:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.post:active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.anime-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevent image from shrinking */
}

.anime-details {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rating {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
@foreach (var anime in Model.Animes)
{
  <div class="post">
    <a href="url">
      <div class="anime-image-container">
        <img class="anime-image" src="@anime.Image">
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="anime-details">
      <p class="title">@anime.Title</p>
      <p class="rating">Рейтинг</p>
    </div>
  </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: .container is a flex container and will dispatch its content rows by rows. What you look for is known as masonry layout and actually the most solid method to do so is via the famous masonry script https://masonry.desandro.com/ . (grid has an experimental feature, but  not really usable yet)

Comment: What is that templating code? Please [edit] your post to include _all_ the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

This layout is called masonry layout. Google it.
Here's an example of what you're trying to accomplish:

CSS code:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.masonry {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 1em;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  max-width: 768px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width:100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="item">Some text here to fill in the gap</div>
  <div class="item">This text however is pretty longgg....... More random text to make height bigger. This is example.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="item">Some text here to fill in the gap</div>
  <div class="item">Thger. This is example.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicintetur adipisicing eg elit.</div>
  <div class="item">Some text here to fill in the gap</div>
  <div class="item">This text however is pret...... More random text to make height bigger. This is example.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conseclit.</div>
  <div class="item">Some text here to fill in the gap</div>
  <div class="item">This texexample.</div>
</div>
```